# How to create a form to allow only inputs in FileMaker?

Tags: filemaker

I am creating something like a workflow application where students will enter their hours and their supervisors will approve their weekly hours.

When the student logs in and sees the layout, I will automatically populate the student id so that they will not be able to enter other student hours, also the students should not be able to see other entries of the tblHours table by navigating using the top navigation pane?

I am a newbie to FileMaker, please suggest alternative methods if I am doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

One usual approach is to use global fields for the input and after they submit the form, populate your regular fields using a script.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use custom record level access for the privilege set in Security settings. This approach can stop users viewing records not belonged to them throughout the system.